# nested, closed, bounded sets in complete metric space is non empty

Tags: real-analysis

I am self-studying Real Analysis and doing the exercise 3.21 of Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.

[image]

I got the same proof idea, but cannot reach the argument that ``$x$ must belong to $E_n$ for all n.''

Pulling things out of context, we would have the following claim: If ($E_n$) is a nested sequence of closed and bounded sets in a complete metric space $X$ with $E_n\supseteq E_{n+1}$. Then, $\cap_1^\infty E_n$ is non-empty.

The proof idea is to construct a sequence $(x_n)$ s.t. $x_n\in E_n$. The limit of the sequence $x:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n$ exists in the metric space X because of completeness.

With the fact that x is the limit of $(x_n)$, I can only say $x_n$ would get closer to $x$ by an arbitrarily small $\epsilon$, but if $x$ happens to be located at some (overlapping) ``boundary'' of the closed sets $x_n$, such $\epsilon$-fluctuation could go outside of some $E_n$.

In the provided proof, the author used some logical schema like (with predicate $P$) if $P(x_n)$ for all $n>m$, then $P(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_m)$. This is obviously not true.

I would appreciate much if anyone could construct a more rigorous proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a metric space, a subset $E \subseteq X$ is closed if and only if whenever $x_n$ is a sequence contained in $E$ that converges to $x$ in $X$, then $x \in E$. (If you haven't seen this before, you should have a go proving it: the standard method is by contrapositive, assuming there's a sequence $x_n \in E$ that converges to $x \notin E$ and showing that $x$ is a point that makes the complement of $E$ not open.) This is where the proof uses the fact that the sets $E_n$ are closed: this statement isn't true for non-closed $E$.

For each $E_n$, the sequence $(x_m: m\geq n)$ is a convergent sequence contained in the closed set $E_n$, so the limit $x$ is in $E_n$ because it's closed. This shows that $x$ is in all $E_n$, so it's in the intersection.

Comment: Hi, I am getting through your if-and-only-if argument (and also the original exercise) by using the fact that if x_n->x, x is a limit point of range(x_n). Then, x is in closure(range(x_n)), which is a subset of the closure of E, which is the closed set E itself. I believe my argument is also valid?

Comment: I think so, yes. It might be worth looking back at some of the material related to closures to solidify the idea: i.e. if you've defined closure as 'the set plus its limit points', then the key points that are analogous to what I said in my answer are the proofs that 'closures are closed' and 'the closure of a closed set is the closed set itself'. But once you've seen them and understood them once, you can just use this as an alternate definition of closed, which is what Rudin did in this exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and explanation.